# djangosaml2: cannot serialize IdpUnspecified('No IdP to send to given the premises',) (type IdpUnspecified)

Tags: django, saml

I am trying to get djangosaml2 working, I have tried configured the settings as best as I can against https://openidp.feide.no/ But I am getting the following error when I navigate to /saml2/login/:

```
cannot serialize IdpUnspecified('No IdP to send to given the premises',) (type IdpUnspecified)
```

This is what I have in settings

```
LOGIN_URL = '/saml2/login/'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
from os import path            
import saml2
BASEDIR = path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))
SAML_CONFIG = {                
    # full path to the xmlsec1 binary programm
    'xmlsec_binary': '/usr/bin/xmlsec1',

    # your entity id, usually your subdomain plus the url to the metadata view
    'entityid': 'http://localhost:8000/saml2/metadata/',

    # directory with attribute mapping
    'attribute_map_dir': path.join(BASEDIR, 'attributemaps'),

    # this block states what services we provide
    'service': {
        # we are just a lonely SP       
        'sp' : {
            'name': 'Just a saml test SP',  
            'endpoints': {     
                # url and binding to the assetion consumer service view
                # do not change the binding or service name
                'assertion_consumer_service': [ 
                    ('http://localhost:8000/saml2/acs/',
                     saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),       
                    ],
                # url and binding to the single logout service view
                # do not change the binding or service name
                'single_logout_service': [      
                    ('http://localhost:8000/saml2/ls/',
                     saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),   
                    ],
                },

             # attributes that this project need to identify a user
            'required_attributes': ['uid'], 

             # attributes that may be useful to have but not required
            'optional_attributes': ['eduPersonAffiliation'],

            # in this section the list of IdPs we talk to are defined
            'idp': {
                # we do not need a WAYF service since there is
                # only an IdP defined here. This IdP should be
                # present in our metadata

                # the keys of this dictionary are entity ids
                'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php': {
                    'single_sign_on_service': {
                        saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT: 'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
                        },
                    'single_logout_service': {
                        saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT: 'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },

    # where the remote metadata is stored
    'metadata': {
        'local': [path.join(BASEDIR, 'remote_metadata.xml')],
        },

    # set to 1 to output debugging information
    'debug': 1,

    # certificate
    'key_file': path.join(BASEDIR, 'mycert.key'),  # private part
    'cert_file': path.join(BASEDIR, 'mycert.pem'),  # public part

    # own metadata settings
    'contact_person': [
        {'given_name': 'James',
         'sur_name': 'Lin',
         'company': 'Company',
         'email_address': 'james@james.com',
         'contact_type': 'technical'},
        ],
    # you can set multilanguage information here
    'organization': {
        'name': [('Company', 'en'),],
        'display_name': [('Company', 'en')],
        'url': [('http://www.company.com', 'en')],
        },
    'valid_for': 24,  # how long is our metadata valid
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OKAY! 
I got the old instruction from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangosaml2/0.1.0
But when I install via PIP it installed the latest version, the latest instruction is here https://bitbucket.org/lgs/djangosaml2

After digging through the code I finally found out the `idp` key should have been 'idpsso', see below:

```
'idpsso': {        
                # we do not need a WAYF service since there is
                # only an IdP defined here. This IdP should be
                # present in our metadata       

                # the keys of this dictionary are entity ids
                'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php': {
                    'single_sign_on_service': {     
                        saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT: 'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
                        },
                    'single_logout_service': {      
                        saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT: 'https://openidp.feide.no/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
```

Comment: I had the same problem but it was resolved by removing `'idp'` part from configuration since idp data is already present in `remote_metadata.xml` file. Have you tried this? Maybe changing key from `'idp'` to `'idpsso'` only has a side effect of not overriding the idp data that is loaded from metadata since`'idpsso'` is never loaded or used?

Comment: Here is the part of the documentation that explains this parametar http://pythonhosted.org/pysaml2/howto/config.html#idp

Comment: i am wondering what to put in remote_metadata.xml !! I am facing the same issue.